# What is the 41GB of "System" on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, storage

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro, and it's running out of storage:[image: My Hard Drive]. What I cannot understand is, what is the 41GB of "System" (grey). I installed an app called Disk Inventory X which scanned my drive and said that the largest folder on my device was Applications, which is only 26GB. Here is a screenshot of the results:
[image: Disk Inventory X results]
What is causing this? Is it all the non-application/photos/documents/iTunes stuff combined? Or is it something else?
Here are my System Specs if that helps:[image: System Specs]